# Java - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to load resource

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am writing a application for my computer and it required a config file, I put my file into my resources folder and fetch it using `URL configUrl = getClass().getResource(configURL)` and then read it with `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(configUrl.openStream()))` and then I cycle through all the lines and return the string of data, but when I try to create a `JSONObject` with the string, it returns the error when I run it. It works fine inside netbeans but when I run it in a .jar it doesn't work.

I have been working on this issue for hours and I finally had a stroke of luck when I got it to get the string data from the file, but then this issue happend and I don't know what to do, (I am new to java so I am not a expert)

The java file is this:

```java
public class ProjectName {

    public static String configURL = "/config.json";
    public static String configSource = "";
    public static JSONObject config;

    public static void main(string[] args) {

        System.out.println("Fetching config...");

        config = new JSONObject(MO.fetchConfig()); // This is where the error comes in

        System.out.println("Config fetched");

    }

    public String fetchConfig() {

        URL configUrl = getClass().getResource(configURL);

        try {

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(configUrl.openStream()))) {

                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    configSource += inputLine;

                }

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            errorScreen.main("Couldn't Read Config", "Try redownloading the application", "CRC_001");

        }

        return configSource;

    }

}
```

This is my document structure:

```
>root
  >Some xml files
  >src
    >main
      >java
        >com
          >MyName
        >JSON
          >Java files
      >resources
        >config.json
    >test
  >target
```

It gets a string of `config.json`'s contents but then when converted into a JSONObject it throws that error.

I am using Netbeans, maven, and on a macbook if that holds any value

Extra Info:

Result of `getClass().getResource(configURL)` : `jar:file:/Users/{myUser}/NetBeansProjects/{projectFolder}/target/{projectName}-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/config.json`

Entire error report:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at com.{myName}.{projectName}.{javaFileName}.main({javaFileName}.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Could you please post the entire stacktrace? I know that your path is not caught, since you are calling getClass() means you are in root class package so since there you try to find next folder .getResource() to next folder.

Comment: I don't know what a "stacktrace" is? I added more information and hopfully what I added is what you're looking for

Comment: try to use this URL url = new URL("classpath:config.json");

Comment: stacktrace is what you added, it is steps that were logged when getting an error,..

Comment: I tried the URL code you gave it and it gave me this `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath`. Also call me an idiot but I think by "stacktrace is what you added" means the "error report" is the strack trace, if so, good, if not, sorry.

Comment: is the same error that you got? @Phayden

Comment: The `MalformedURLException` is a new error, I got it when trying to print the return value of `new URL("classpath:config.json")` since it didn't allow me to use it to get the resource since it wasn't a string

Comment: Oh right, so please try to use this `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("config.json");` else add /config.json, this should work, in your code doesn't work because you are not using class loader.

Comment: I used `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("config.json");` and I got the same `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to turn the content into a JSONObject

Comment: could you please share your code on some repo so that I can help you? @Phayden

Comment: A repo? I don't know any repos